Is there a way to include parallel run steps in a batch endpoint pipeline?
I currently have a batch endpoint which can run execution in parallel. I am looking to move this job into a batch endpoint pipeline so I can have subsequent steps process the outputs.
I have been able to deploy multi stage pipeline when dealing with 2 command steps as per guidance. However, when I try and include a parallel pipeline. I cannot get it to deploy. Non of the examples i can see on Azureml https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/tree/main/cli/endpoints/batch deal with using a parallel step in the pipeline deployments
Is there a way to include parallel run steps in a batch endpoint pipeline?
if so what changes would i need to make to below
batch_deployment.yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/pipelineComponentBatchDeployment.schema.json
name: pipeline-test
endpoint_name: ptest
type: pipeline
component: pipeline.yaml
settings:
    continue_on_step_failure: true
    default_compute: <compute>

pipeline.yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/pipelinecomponent.schema.json
type: pipeline

name: pipeline

inputs:
  data:
    type: string  
    
outputs: 
  outputs:
    type: uri_folder
    mode: upload

jobs:
  process_data:
    type: parallel
    component: process_data.yaml
    inputs:
      data: ${{parent.inputs.input_val}}
      model_file: azureml:<model_name>

  
  trigger_next_step:
    type: command
    component: trigger_next_step.yaml
    inputs:
      data: ${{parent.jobs.process_data.outputs.output_val}}
    outputs:
      scores: 
        mode: upload
        path: ${{parent.outputs.scores}}

trigger next step is a command job and was tested with 2 command jobs so i know that isn't the problem here.
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/parallelComponent.schema.json
type: parallel
name: parallel_embed
description: parallel embed
display_name: parallel_embedding
compute: azureml:reip-etl-mip

input_data: ${{inputs.data}}
inputs:
  model_file:
    type: mlflow_model
outputs:
    output_folder:
      mode: rw_mount
      type: uri_folder

resources:
  instance_count: 1
max_concurrency_per_instance: 1

logging_level: "INFO"
mini_batch_size: '1'

task:
    type: run_function
    code: "./"
    entry_script: batch_score.py
    environment:
      conda_file: environment.yaml
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-ubuntu18.04
    
    program_arguments: >-
        --model_file ${{inputs.model_file}}
        --output_folder ${{outputs.output_folder}}

When I do attempt to deploy the endpoint using above. I get an error which I think means I need to add an additional key : value for component name but where ever I add it, it fails, so not sure if this is just a red herring.
(UserError) Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
Code: UserError
Message: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
Additional Information:Type: ComponentName
Info: {
    "value": "managementfrontend"
}Type: Correlation
Info: {
    "value": {
        "operation": "",
        "request": ""
    }
}Type: Environment
Info: {
    "value": ""
}Type: Location
Info: {
    "value": ""
}Type: Time
Info: {
    "value": ""
}


try setting max_concurrency_per_instance to 2

According to this documentation in YAML syntax the jobs currently you can give is command jobs and sweep jobs only.
That is command type or sweep job type components only.
But the definition in the latest JSON schema  has more type than this two, including parallel type.
The error you are getting because the source JSON schema
https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/parallelComponent.schema.json

doesn't exist.
You can check this here
So, give it as inline instead of giving it as component.
Here is the sample just change the $schema to
https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/pipelineComponent.schema.json.
In your case it's something like below.
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/pipelinecomponent.schema.json
type: pipeline

name: pipeline

inputs:
  data:
    type: string  
    
outputs: 
  outputs:
    type: uri_folder
    mode: upload

jobs:
  process_data:
    type: parallel
    compute: azureml:reip-etl-mip
    inputs:
      model_file:
        type: mlflow_model
    outputs:
        output_folder:
          mode: rw_mount
          type: uri_folder

    resources:
      instance_count: 1
      max_concurrency_per_instance: 2

    logging_level: "INFO"
    mini_batch_size: '1'

    task:
        type: run_function
        code: "./"
        entry_script: batch_score.py
        environment:
          conda_file: environment.yaml
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-ubuntu18.04
    
        program_arguments: >-
            --model_file ${{inputs.model_file}}
            --output_folder ${{outputs.output_folder}}

  
  trigger_next_step:
    type: command
    component: trigger_next_step.yaml
    inputs:
      data: ${{parent.jobs.process_data.outputs.output_val}}
    outputs:
      scores: 
        mode: upload
        path: ${{parent.outputs.scores}}

